# How to get row through Find function?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop the cells of a range then check if every cell has a match in the range `rngIng`. If there is one, get the row where the match is and later, copy the value of the offset cell in column B and paste its value in column J.

When I try to get the row there is a variable type error.

Here is where the issue is: `row = .rngIng.Find(What:=Name, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).row`.

```vb
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    'Find which is the last row with data in column "C"
    ' Define range with data in column "C"
    Dim rngIng As Range
    Dim lastRowIng As Integer
    With ws.Columns("C")
        lastRowIng = .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Set rngIng = .Range(Cells(2, "C"), Cells(lastRowIng, "C"))
    End With
    
    'Find which is the last row with data in column "A"
    Dim lastRowRef As Integer
    With ws.Columns("A")
        lastRowRef = .Cells(.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    End With
     

    Dim i, j, row As Long
    i = 2
    j = 2
    
    For i = 2 To lastRowRef
        Dim Name As Variant
        Name = ws.Cells(i, "A").Value
        With ws
            row = .rngIng.Find(What:=Name, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole).row
        End With

        If row <> 0 Then
            ws.Cells(j, "J").Value = ws.Cells(row, "B").Value
            j = j + 1
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `row = rngIng.Find()` without the `.`

Comment: ...but it will error if there's no match, so you should do something like `Dim f As range: Set f = rngIng.Find(...): If Not f Is Nothing Then:...`

Comment: In this case, it probably errors because you have declared *lastRowRef* `As Integer` instead of `As Long`.

Comment: @Tim Williams I did the changes you recommended me, but if ```Dim row As range: Set row = rngIng.Find(...): If Not f Is Nothing Then:...``` ,then an error 91 happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, j As Long
    Dim rngIng As Range, c As Range, f As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    ' Define range with data in column "C"
    Set rngIng = ws.Range("C2:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row)
    
    j = 2
    For Each c In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row).Cells 'loop Col A
        Set f = rngIng.Find(What:=c.Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)       'search col C
        If Not f Is Nothing Then                                                      'any match?
            ws.Cells(j, "J").Value = f.EntireRow.Columns("B").Value
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
    
End Sub
```